# Creating a new file in SSH enabled system using JSCH

Tags: jsch

I want to create a new file in ssh enabled system using JSCH. Can any one please suggest me some examples of connect to the ssh system using JSCH.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html
This is a simple example on how to exec a command over SSH with the command `touch yourfile` it will create a file on your distant system.